# struggling to create dependencies in java for IBM speech to text

Tags: java, maven, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I know this is ridiculous , but I have been struggling to move on from step 0 which is to create dependencies for the project!

I want to to make a simple speech to text app that can transcribe a file for me .

How the code will look like :

```
package com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text;


import com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.http.HttpMediaType;
import com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.security.Authenticator;
import com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.security.IamAuthenticator;
import com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.v1.SpeechToText;
import com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.v1.model.RecognizeOptions;
import com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.v1.model.SpeechRecognitionResults;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

/**
 * Recognize a sample wav file and print the transcript into the console output.
 * Make sure you are using UTF-8 to print messages; otherwise, you will see
 * question marks.
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Authenticator authenticator = new IamAuthenticator("-key");
        SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText(authenticator);

        File audio = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\curl\\test.mp3");

        RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions.Builder().audio(audio).contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_MP3)
                .build();
        ;
        try {
            options = new RecognizeOptions.Builder().audio(audio).contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_MP3).build();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SpeechRecognitionResults transcript = service.recognize(options).execute().getResult();
        System.out.println(transcript.toString());

    }

}
```

According to [github](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/master/speech-to-text) and [IBM website](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=java)  You are supposed to create dependencies using maven or Gradle for your project and I have no idea how to do that !

I Don't understand how to create dependencies , Do I have to create a new file in the project and call it pom.xml and paste the text and run it as maven install (because that didn't work for me ) or  what exactly should I do ? Please help as it's been almost 3 days and I'm struggling in like step 0!

---

Update:

I got these Errors when I click maven build with the goal as "clean install"

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/User/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/User/eclipse/java-2020-12/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/User/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/User/eclipse/java-2020-12/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< com.ibm.watson:my-app >------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\User\Desktop\waaaaaaaaaats\my-app\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ my-app ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\User\Desktop\waaaaaaaaaats\my-app\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\User\Desktop\waaaaaaaaaats\my-app\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.740 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-18T18:45:47+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-app: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

---

The pom.xml File that I used  :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.ibm.watson</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibm.watson</groupId>
      <artifactId>speech-to-text</artifactId>
      <version>9.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

new Error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------< com.ibm.watson:my-app >------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\User\Desktop\my-app\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ my-app ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\User\Desktop\my-app\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\User\Desktop\my-app\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[4,35] package com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[5,39] package com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.security does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[6,39] package com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.security does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[7,40] package com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.v1 does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[8,46] package com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.v1.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[9,46] package com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.v1.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[22,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Authenticator
  location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[22,51] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class IamAuthenticator
  location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[23,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SpeechToText
  location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[23,44] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SpeechToText
  location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[27,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RecognizeOptions
  location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[27,100] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable HttpMediaType
  location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[27,64] package RecognizeOptions does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[31,91] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable HttpMediaType
  location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[31,55] package RecognizeOptions does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[37,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SpeechRecognitionResults
  location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[INFO] 16 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.107 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-18T19:48:34+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-app: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[4,35] package com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[5,39] package com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.security does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[6,39] package com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.security does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[7,40] package com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.v1 does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[8,46] package com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.v1.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[9,46] package com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.v1.model does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[22,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Authenticator
[ERROR]   location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[22,51] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class IamAuthenticator
[ERROR]   location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[23,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class SpeechToText
[ERROR]   location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[23,44] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class SpeechToText
[ERROR]   location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[27,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class RecognizeOptions
[ERROR]   location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[27,100] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable HttpMediaType
[ERROR]   location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[27,64] package RecognizeOptions does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[31,91] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable HttpMediaType
[ERROR]   location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[31,55] package RecognizeOptions does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Desktop/my-app/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/speech_to_text/Main.java:[37,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class SpeechRecognitionResults
[ERROR]   location: class com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text.Main
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Learning maven is worth the trouble. This tutorial looks ok: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/your-first-maven-project.html

Comment: I don't want to create a maven project , I want to add the dependencies to my project ! How do you do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a maven project for this where its structure might look like this

```
my-app
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- ibm
    |               `-- watson
    |                   `-- speech_to_text
    |                       `-- Main.java
```

**src, main, java, com, ibm, watson, speech_to_text** are the directories.

The content of the `pom.xml` might look like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.ibm.watson</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibm.watson</groupId>
      <artifactId>ibm-watson</artifactId>
      <version>9.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This includes your dependencies,

After this, you need to have maven installed in your machine to compile and run it. After installing maven you can run

```
mvn clean install    OR    mvn package
```

to compile/build the project. This will create a JAR file for you.

Finally, you can run the project with

```
java YOUR_JAR_NAME.jar
```

## Suggestions:

Don't use the package `com.ibm.watson.speech_to_text` in your java file instead use your own e.g. `com.mycompany.app` so your directory structure will also change as per the package name i.e.

```
my-app
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- mycompany
    |               `-- app
    |                   `-- Main.java
```

`pom.xml` content will also change according to this

```
<groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
```

Comment: Are you sure that is how it's supposed to be done in eclipse ? I have eclipse and it already have maven installed in it , am I supposed to install maven again separately ?

Comment: I already did install maven separately I'm just asking if that is how you are supposed to do it in eclipse !

Comment: ok... let me tell you exactly what I did in eclipse!
I created a new "Maven project" nad called it my-app 

I then changed the pom.xml file and added the dependency "ibm-watson"
and then I right clicked and chose "Maven" ---> "Maven builds" ---> and I set the goal to be "clean install" and I clicked run and I got a bunch of errors (see the new updated post about the error ) ... this is in details of what I did in eclipse!

Comment: Please share the pom.xml
Does it have source and target configured? Seems like you are using old version of Java as well.

Comment: also I tried to do mvn clean install after changing cmd path to the pom.xml folder and I got almost the same error as the eclipse error!

Comment: ok!
Check the updated edit on the original post! I will add the pom.xml file that I used!

Comment: Please share your Java version using `java --version` command in CMD.

Comment: If it is Java 5 you need to update it to Java 7 or Java 8. That's what the error says.

Comment: java 15.0.1 2020-10-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I just updated it to java 15.0.1 .... Now eclipse is not working ... I will try to update eclipse too!

Comment: Java 15 and installed maven version are not compatible.
Instead use Java 8 and existing maven. It will work.

Comment: so should I uninstall java 15 and install java 8 instead ?

Comment: When installing Java 8 you can add `<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>` above the `dependencies` tag in pom.xml

Comment: You can install both and set the one you want to use in environment variable 'path'

Comment: I have uninstalled 15 and installed 8 ... re-arranged the the environment variable to point to to java 8 ... I also added the properties as you mentioned to the pom.xml file .... I ran the mvn test in both eclipse and cmd and got a new error in both of them (same error!)!

Comment: Please change the package name of your java file as I've mentioned in the Suggestions heading of my answer and then try